# How could I make "Do not Disturb" block Facebook Messenger popup?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, facebook-messenger, do-not-disturb

I have DND (Do not disturb) enable from 8:00 - 17:00 (Priority only), but the Facebook Messenger still can popup, how could I make `Do not disturb` feature to work on Facebook Messenger? 
I'm using Sony Xperia XA1Plus on 8.0 Oreo

Comment: Have you enabled "Block when screen is on" & "Block when screen is off" in "Block visual disturbances" in Do not disturb settings?

Comment: @reddy: yes, i did. Dnd https://imgur.com/gallery/xEB3D7X